# Pointer pointing to garbage value after passing the address in a function

Tags: c

The two pointers, keyClickPtr and secondPtr always possess a garbage value instead of possessing the values of keyClick and second variable from the keyPress function. I am trying to check if there are any trailing characters except a new line char entered by the user after the allowed characters which are, C, P or E. Input example, I entered, was "we".

Main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void keyPress(void);
void trCharsInKeyPress(char* keyClickPtr, char* secondPtr);
    
void main(void) {
    keyPress();
    return 0;
    }
```

Function:

```
  void keyPress(void) {
    
    char keyClick = '\0', second = '\0';
    
    printf("Enter C, P or E: ");
    scanf("%c%c", &keyClick, &second);
    
    if (second != '\n') trCharsInKeyPress(&keyClick, &second);

    return 0;
}
```

Function:

```
void trCharsInKeyPress(char* keyClickPtr, char* secondPtr) //issue here 
    {
        while (*secondPtr != '\n') {
    
            printf("No trailing characters allowed. Press try again: ");
            scanf("%c%c", keyClickPtr, secondPtr);
        }
return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How do you determine that the pointers contain "garbage values"?  And do you mean that the pointers themselves are invalid, or that the locations to which they point contain unexpected data?  What are the actual garbage values you observe?

Comment: Although it doesn't explain the behavior you describe, I suggest you consider using `getchar()` or `fgets()` for this task, instead of `scanf()`.

Comment: The `return 0;` in `void trCharsInKeyPress(...)` seems out of place. Is that the *real* code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are greatly complicating user-input trying to use a *formatted-input* function (and further complication matters by not handling the fact that `"%c"` (and `"%[..]"` and `"%n"`) do not discard leading whitespace. Just one of many pitfalls for new C programmers who attempt to use `scanf()` for user input.

Instead, you should use a *line-oriented* input function like `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` to read and consume and entire line of user input. Using a sufficiently sized buffer (or `getline()` allocates dynamically for you), it doesn't matter how many characters the user enters, you read them all, and in your case, you only care about the first character -- which makes things quite easy.

**Requiring Single-Character Input**

Since this was one of your requirements you can handle this simply by checking whether the character array filled by `fgets()` contains the `'\n'` as the second-character in the array. While this check ***makes no difference to your use of a valid character*** you can remind the user that he is only to enter a single character as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int getkeypress (char *line)
{
    while (1) { /* loop continually until valid input, manual EOF or empty-line */
        fputs ("\nEnter C, P or E: ", stdout);                  /* prompt for input */
        if (!fgets (line, MAXC, stdin)) {                       /* read entire line */
            puts ("(user canceled input, manual EOF)");         /* manual EOF case */
            return 0;
        }
        else if (*line == '\n')                                 /* empty line case */
            return 0;
        /* optional -- extra chars, does not effect validity C, P, or E as 1st char */
        else if (line[1] != '\n')
            fputs ("  error: trailing characters not allowed\n", stderr);
        else if (*line == 'C' || *line == 'P' || *line == 'E')  /* good input, done */
            break;
        else
            fputs ("  error: invalid input.\n", stderr);        /* all other errors */
    }
    
    return 1;
}

int main (void) {
    
    char buf[MAXC];
    
    while (getkeypress (buf))                       /* while good input */
        printf ("Good input: %c\n", *buf);
}
```

(**note:** the character array `buf` is declared in `main()` and then the buffer is passed as a parameter to the `getkeypress()` function that stores the input in the buffer and then returns `1` on success, or `0` in the event a manual `EOF` was generated by the user pressing <kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> on windows) or the user ended input by simply pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> with an empty-line)

The approach to user input is the same regardless of which input function you use. You loop continually until the user provides valid input, ***checking the return*** of the input function used and applying any criteria you have to determine if the input is valid or invalid. When valid input is received, you simply `break;` the input-loop and return success.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getCPE

Enter C, P or E: Charlie Pappa Echo
  error: trailing characters not allowed

Enter C, P or E: c
  error: invalid input.

Enter C, P or E: P
Good input: P

Enter C, P or E: E
Good input: E

Enter C, P or E: C
Good input: C

Enter C, P or E: Catfish
  error: trailing characters not allowed

Enter C, P or E:
```

**Using 1<sup>st</sup> Character Regardless of How Many Are Entered**

As mentioned above, it isn't necessary to limit the user's input to a single character if all you care about is whether the first character entered was `'C'`, `'P'`, or `'E'`. You can simply choose to ignore all characters after the first, while using any valid `'C'`, `'P'`, or `'E'` entered as the first character. By using a *line-oriented* input function -- all characters are consumed (up to the limit of the array or block of memory  used for storage). In that sense, it doesn't matter if there are additional characters entered, so long as the first character is valid.

That actually makes the function simpler by removing the error associated with trailing characters, e.g.

```
int getkeypress (char *line)
{
    while (1) { /* loop continually until valid input, manual EOF or empty-line */
        fputs ("\nEnter C, P or E: ", stdout);                  /* prompt for input */
        if (!fgets (line, MAXC, stdin)) {                       /* read entire line */
            puts ("(user canceled input, manual EOF)");         /* manual EOF case */
            return 0;
        }
        else if (*line == '\n')                                 /* empty line case */
            return 0;
        else if (*line == 'C' || *line == 'P' || *line == 'E')  /* good input, done */
            break;
        
        fputs ("  error: invalid input.\n", stderr);            /* handle error */
    }
    
    return 1;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getCPE2

Enter C, P or E: Charlie Pappa Echo
Good input: C

Enter C, P or E: c
  error: invalid input.

Enter C, P or E: P
Good input: P

Enter C, P or E: E
Good input: E

Enter C, P or E: C
Good input: C

Enter C, P or E: Catfish
Good input: C

Enter C, P or E:
```

Note above, the only difference is input beginning with `'C'`, `'P'`, or `'E'` is taken as valid -- which if that is all you really care about, is fine.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. If you absolutely must use `scanf()` it is doable -- but only once you understand the function well enough to know why you shouldn't use it to begin with. If you must use it, let me know and I'm happy to help further.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void keyPress(void);

int main(void)
{
    keyPress();
    return 0;
}


void keyPress(void)
{
    char userInput[100];
    bool valid = false;

    while (!valid)
    {
        printf("Enter C, P or E: ");                // query for user input
        fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin); // get the input
        userInput[strlen(userInput) - 1] = '\0';    // removes the \n at end when the user press enter

        if(strlen(userInput) != 1){
            printf("No trailing characters allowed. Press try again.\n");
        } else{
            if (userInput[0] == 'C' || userInput[0] == 'P' || userInput[0] == 'E' || userInput[0] =='c'||userInput[0] =='p'|| userInput[0] =='e')
                valid = true;
            else
                printf("Must be C, P or E. Press try again.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Your original code just seems you don't need to return the value anywhere but if you do just make a pointer to pass back to the main or leave a comment and ill edit the code to show you how to bring the value back to main.